# Execution Reverted Details

Tags: ropsten, infura, web3j, java

I am writing code in Java and trying to calculated potential gas units, for a function call on my methods.
I am trying to do so by using infura as a provider for my web3 Instance,
and then created a transaction and using the ethEstimateGas() function, but when I do so The response returned is {"jsonrpc":"2.0","id":1,"error":{"code":-32000,"message":"execution reverted"}}
Which is not really descriptive, I would like to know what am I doing wrong or is there any other way to do so:
Code For Reference:

````
        Type address = new Address({My address here});
        inputParams.add(address);

        Type value = new Uint(new BigInteger("1000"));
        inputParams.add(value);

        Function function = new Function(
                "withdraw",
                inputParams,
                Collections.<TypeReference<?>>emptyList());

        String functionEncoderString = FunctionEncoder.encode(function);
        ////
        Web3j web3j = Web3j.build(new HttpService("https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/{my_API_KWY}"));

        BigInteger gasPrice = web3j.ethGasPrice().send().getGasPrice();
        Transaction t = new Transaction({fromAddress}, null, gasPrice, null, "0x3DDbe06F45B98a8613C95319Af8CA37BCC5d5c92", null, functionEncoderString);
        EthEstimateGas amount = web3j.ethEstimateGas(t).send();```
````

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your exact same code but on `Rinkeby` and it worked just fine.

For `Ropsten`, it is a little bit different since `Block gas limit` is not fixed and varies a lot.

Similar issues stating this issue:

[Gas estimation errored with the following message error upon contract deployment](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/89764/gas-estimation-errored-with-the-following-message-error-upon-contract-deployment)

[Gas estimation failed” on Ropsten using MetaMask!](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/53225/gas-estimation-failed-on-ropsten-using-metamask)